# Boolean simplification for FRQI

Tags: qiskit

I recently took part in a hackathon, and following that I would like to keep working on the project, which consists in developing an FRQI circuit.

I was working on its optimization through boolean simplification, as explained in the Qiskit documentation: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/image-processing-frqi-neqr.html#5.-Compression. However, I did not manage to make it work, and with some input matrices I get part of the images which have wrong values.

Here is what I understood so far:

1. First, I group the pixels by intensity.
2. Second, using [sympy.to_dnf](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.to_dnf), I simplify the binary expressions computed from the pixel positions of each group. First, are there methods faster than `to_dnf` for large groups please? I read about Espresso for instance.
3. Third, I add the CX gates and controlled rotations based on the results of the latter. When it is simplified to one product of boolean variables, the controlled qubits are only the one figuring in it. I apply the required CX gates before. But I wonder about the angle of the rotation to apply. Should I multiply it by the number of pixels in the group?
4. When the simplified expression has still several products, I am not sure of how to handle it. Currently I just apply the step 3. for every product. However I should be wrong because the generated circuit does not always work. So I was thinking if there might be some commutativity issues or other aspects to pay attention to, regarding the theory of quantum physics.

If you would like to see the code, you can find it [here](https://github.com/LouisJustinTALLOT/2023_IonQ_Remote_Somervillains/blob/ab591ca28a3cba0b7ae038e63cc6366a4fa0d238/part1.py). The non optimized function is `encode`, and the current optimized function which does not work is `encode_compress`. Sorry for the code being slightly messy, but I aim at making sure the implemented principles are correct before considering implementation errors.

If you need any additional information, please let me know,

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Best regards,

jd6

Comment: Could you be please more specific? Actually, I do not see any question on your post.

Comment: The objective is to get a better understanding of how boolean simplification for FRQI works, to be able to implement a successful circuit. My main questions are related to 3. and 4. First, based on this chapter (page 11) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tPz_mRZLAUNNlasRt0rsUkN8C39JJNEv/view?usp=sharing the suggested circuit does not give the expected result when I implemented it, so I am wondering what could be wrong, if it is in the theory or my implementation. If it is my implementation, what should be the rotation angle for each group? How to handle multiple product terms?